# Plotly displays discrete colors instead of a colorscale

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I'm learning Plotly Choropleth maps by doing some very basic examples. I'm plotting countries' GDP on a world map. Instead of a colorscale, from lower to higher GDP, I get a map with a discrete color for every country.

I suspect it might have to do with the GDP in the original dataset being a string, e.g. '23,350,230'. I have converted it to float, and confirmed the conversion worked.

```
fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="Code",
                    color="GDP",
                    hover_name="Country",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.show()
```

I have also tried using other values for `color_continuous_scale`, [including once from here](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-colorscales-are-available-in-plotly-and-which-are-the-default/2079), and removing the parameter all together, the result was still the same map with discrete colors.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, thank you!

---

EDIT

To reproduce the issue:
The dataset is from Kaggle and can be downloaded [here](https://www.kaggle.com/theworldbank/world-bank-gdp-ranking). It's formatting is not great, with many empty/redundant rows and 3 empty columns, so I have done some steps to preprocess the data. Btw the preprocessing if pretty rough so if you have any suggestions on how I could improve it, it is very welcome!

```
df = pd.read_csv("gdp-ppp.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(df.index[0:4])
df = df.drop(df.index[195:])
df = df.drop(df.index[-4:])

df.columns = ['Code', 'Rank', 'Country', 'GDP']

i = 4
for gdp in df["GDP"]:
    gdp = gdp.replace(",", "")
    df["GDP"][i] = float(gdp)
    i += 1

for gdp in df["GDP"]:
    if type(gdp) != type(1.1):
        print(gdp)
```

This *seems* to work, the `print(gdp)` in the last loop is never called, and the dataframe looks nice and clean. So that's when I use the code above to create the choropleth map, which is created, and the data is displayed correctly in the bar on the left, but the coloring is discrete. [Here's the screenshot of the map I get.](https://ibb.co/JpZhGvS)

Comment: Hi Yulia, welcome to SO. Could you please provide a reproducible example so that others could run your code and see your errors and help? Here's a how-to if you haven't seen it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RobertMyles, yes, thank you, I should've thought of that! Added all the steps to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, plotly is seeing GDP as a string and thus using discrete colors.  Use `str.replace` to remove the comma from the csv data (and then convert to float).  Something like:

```py
df["GDP"] = df["GDP"].str.replace(",","").astype(float)
```

This would come right after `df.columns = ['Code', 'Rank', 'Country', 'GDP']`, and then remove the `for` loops.

Complete code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 
df = pd.read_csv("gdp-csv-.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 9', 'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(df.index[0:4])
df = df.drop(df.index[195:])
df = df.drop(df.index[-4:])

df.columns = ['Code', 'Rank', 'Country', 'GDP']
df["GDP"] = df["GDP"].str.replace(",","").astype(float)

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="Code",
                    color="GDP",
                    hover_name="Country",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.show()
```

btw, a cleaner way to bring the csv in would be to specify the column with `usecols` and rows with `skiprows`, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
df = pd.read_csv("gdp-csv-.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", usecols=[0,1,3,4], skiprows=4, 
                 skipfooter=122, engine='python')
df.columns = ['Code', 'Rank', 'Country', 'GDP']
df["GDP"] = df["GDP"].str.replace(",","").astype(float)
```

EDIT: added `skipfooter` to `pd.read_csv`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, will try that, and special thanks for the tip about usecols! I wasn't aware we could use the replace method on the whole column, thus used a loop. Do you have any idea why that didn't work? Especially since I used the loop at the end to confirm all entries in the GDP column were of the float type

Comment: not sure why your method does not work, but after running your loop `df.dtypes` still says GDP is as an `object` and not `float64` so then you need an additional line `df[['GDP']] = df[['GDP']].apply(pd.to_numeric)`

Comment: also, I forgot `skipfooter` in the alternate csv import, see edit above.